# Dual Universe of Sets

Tags: set-theory

Multiple set theories support the concept of the Universe as a collection of all sets of a given definition.

A Universe usually operates with the two predicates defined on the sets:

- equality ($=$) is symmetric: if $x = y$, then $y = x$;
- membership ($\in$) is not symmetric: if $x \in y$, then $y \notin x$.

From projective geometry we know about a dual structure that "reflects" the predicates:

- Projective plane $C$: $p$ is a point on a line $l$ ($p \in l$);
- Dual plane $C^*$: $l$ is a point on a line $p$ ($l \in p$);

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(projective_geometry).

We could extend the principle to a Universe of sets:

- $x = y$ in $U$ $\iff$ $y = x$ in $U^*$;
- $x \in y$ in $U$ $\iff$ $y \in x$ in $U^*$;

where $U$ is the Universe, and $U^*$ is the dual Universe of $U$
(meaning $U^*$ is also a valid Universe of sets).

Is there a set theory that supports such a duality?
If not, what is the main difficulty of creating such a theory?
If yes, can it be well-founded?

My understanding is that ZFC does not support duality since it allows an infinite ascending chain of membership in $U$, which becomes an infinite descending chain of membership in $U^*$, making $U^*$ invalid.

Comment: @Subhajit I am using the notation from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#Axioms. $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary sets from the Universe, not the singletons $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$.

Comment: Ok understood, this is some kind of notation differ from usual set notation.

Comment: What do you mean by a theory that "supports" this duality? You've defined a perfectly sensible thing that's interpretable in your original $U$; do you want $U^*$ to have some particular relation to $U$?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine $U^*$ must be a valid Universe in the same set theory. All the statements valid in $U$ should be valid in $U^*$ and vice versa. The defining relations between $U$ and $U^*$ are listed in the question. Clearly, there may be other conditions as well (e.g. "all relations in $U$ and $U^*$ are converse to each other", similar to what we have in projective geometry).

Comment: @MaliceVidrine ZFC is not supporting duality since it allows an infinite ascending chain of membership in $U$, which becomes an infinite descending chain of membership in $U^*$.

Comment: I want a knife, and I want a frying pan. But I don't want to cook on my knife or cut vegetables with my frying pan. Set theory is not projective geometry.

Comment: @AsafKaragila There are multiple set theories servicing as foundations for different approaches in math. Projective geometry suggests a certain view on the math world. It may not be the only one of the kind. Why not having a foundation for the approach?

Comment: Yes, there are different views on set theory. But they are not that different, except New Foundations, which has yet been "battle tested" as an actual useful foundation.

Comment: @AsafKaragila One of the purposes of my question is to better understand the mechanics of existing set theories. I thought, maybe, the only limitation is the foundation axiom. If we remove it (or, maybe, something else) we will get a Dual Universe. It would be interesting to know even from the standard set theory point of view. Projective geometry is not too far from Euclidean. What if the Dual Universe is just around the corner?

Comment: @AlexC - You're correct about the effect of flipping $\in$-chains, of course. But do you want $U^*$ to satisfy the same set theory as $U$? If so, what's the point of it? Ostensibly the point is that this dual universe would behave in *different* useful ways, and it might help to say what you expect those to be. If the axiom of foundation is your only concern, there are plenty of set theories without it, even without going as far as NFU.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I am not expecting any useful outcome from $U^*$. It is merely an exercise to better understand what we can and what we cannot construct with the axioms of set theories. From another hand, finding different ways to express known things (e.g. projective geometry) may bring something unexpected.